# Как реализовать авторизацию на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Как легче, лучше, безопасно осуществить авторизацию на сайте?
Я использую ReactJS.
Мне нужна лёгкая авторизация без регистрации (чтобы я заведомо создал данные: логин, пароль), чтобы человек имел только логин и пароль для доступа к защищённой странице, откуда сможет выполнять действия на сайте.
Так вот вопрос, какую современную технологию можно изучить, и потом в дальнейшем применить для моего сайта?

Comment: https://authjs.dev/ сейчас модно

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите `auth0`

> Ссылка [на документацию](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login)

Comment: Ссылаться на внешний материал конечно хорошо, но также нужно оставлять цитаты (и код если имеется) из ссылок, чтобы пользователи понимали что из ждёт из ссылки, а также это будет полезно если доступ к ресурсу был потерян. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).